# Java Window Event - Maximize. How to hardcode?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

I have a JDesktopPane and a JInternalFrame. I'd like the JInternalFrame to automatically maximize after I make it. How can I hardcode the "maximize window" event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`JInternalFrame.setMaximum(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html#setMaximum%28boolean%29) after you create your frame.

Here is how you can maximize your frame:

```
JInternalFrame frame = ...
frame..setMaximum(true); // Maximize this window to fill up the whole desktop area
```

Comment: yes but I don't want the user to have to press the maximie button

Comment: No no, this will maximize your frame automatically from code, no user interaction needed

Answer (score 1):

Setting the method **setMaximum(boolean b)** of **JInternalFrame** to **"true"** , will maximize it.

**eg:**

```
JInternalFrame.setMaximum(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

- already suggested above: [JInternalFrame#setMaximum(boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html#setMaximum%28boolean%29)
- Another option: [DesktopManager#maximizeFrame(JInternalFrame)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DesktopManager.html#maximizeFrame%28javax.swing.JInternalFrame%29)

  - a bit different behavior when JDesktopPane resized.

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class JInternalFrameMaximumTest {
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    final JDesktopPane desktop = new JDesktopPane();
    Action a1 = new AbstractAction("JInternalFrame#setMaximum") {
      @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JInternalFrame f = new JInternalFrame("#",true,true,true,true);
        desktop.add(f);
        f.setVisible(true);
        try {
          f.setMaximum(true);
        } catch(java.beans.PropertyVetoException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    };
    Action a2 = new AbstractAction("DesktopManager#maximizeFrame(f)") {
      @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JInternalFrame f = new JInternalFrame("#",true,true,true,true);
        desktop.add(f);
        f.setVisible(true);
        desktop.getDesktopManager().maximizeFrame(f);
      }
    };
    JToolBar toolbar = new JToolBar("toolbar");
    toolbar.add(new JButton(a1));
    toolbar.add(new JButton(a2));

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(desktop);
    p.add(toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    return p;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(new JInternalFrameMaximumTest().makeUI());
    f.setSize(640, 240);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```